# Django: getting error NoReverseMatch for reverse

Tags: python, django

**Getting error:**

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'single_view' with arguments '('article', 2013, 12, 12, 'triumphmotorcycleslaunched10newbikesinindia', 16)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(P[article|review|blog|news|video])/(P\d{4})/(P\d{2})/(P\d{2})/(P\w+)/(P\d+)$']

**Here is my URLConf, models and views**

**/urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^(P<post_type>[article|review|blog|news|video])/', include('post.urls', namespace='post_views')),
...
```

**/post/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', PostView.as_view(), name="index"),
  url(r'^(P<year>\d{4})/(P<month>\d{2})/(P<day>\d{2})/(P<slug>\w+)/(P<post_id>\d+)$', PostView.single, name="single_view")
)
```

*and* **get_absolute_url** *in* **models.Post** *class*

**/post/models.py**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('post_views:single_view', args=['article', 2013, 12, 12, str(self.slug).replace('-', ''), self.id])
```

*and view*

**/post/views.py**

```
def single(self, request, post_type, year, month, day, slug, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
    post_single = Post.objects.get(pk=1)

    context = {
        "post_single": post_single,
    }
    return self.render_to_response(context);
```

**Resolver Error:** Tried after @Yeo suggestion

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve
from post.models import Post
p = Post.objects.get(pk=16)
reverse('post_views:single_view', args=['article', 2013, 12, 12, p.slug, p.id])
resolve('/article/2013/12/12/triumphlaunched10newbikesinindia/16/')
```

> Resolver404: {u'path': u'article/2013/12/12/triumphlaunched10newbikesinindia/16/', u'tried': [[], [ (None:vehicle) ^vehicle/>], [ (None:post_views) ^(P[article|review|blog|news|video])/>], [ (None:gallery) ^gallery/>], [ (None:author) ^author/>], [.*)$>], [ (None:None) ^admin/doc/>], [ (admin:admin) ^admin/>], [ (None:None) ^admin_tools/>]]}

Comment: Try removing `'article'` from `args`.

Comment: To better debug NoReverseMatch, please run the reverse command instead and see how the proper format should looks like when you give the full urls, using `resolver` [Resolver Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) And of course run it in your django shell. You'll soon be able to answer your own question :) Good Luck

Comment: @Rohan still not working...

Comment: @Yeo I tried `resolve` but this too raising error.
I tried:
`resolve('article/2013/12/12/triumphlaunched10newbikesinindia/16')`

Comment: try with leading `/` slash `resolve('/article/2013/12/12/triumphlaunched10newbikesinindia/16/')`

Comment: @Yeo tried with leading `/`, but getting same error!

:(

Comment: Can you please include the error message?

Comment: @Yeo, I included errors to Question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expressions are malformed, try replace

```
r'(P<post_type>[article|review|blog|news|video])'
```

with

```
r'(?P<post_type>article|review|blog|news|video)'
```

Note queston signs and absence of square brackets.

Similary, replace

```
r'^(P<year>\d{4})/(P<month>\d{2})/(P<day>\d{2})/(P<slug>\w+)/(P<post_id>\d+)$
```

with

```
r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>\w+)/(?P<post_id>\d+)$
```

Comment: You saved my lots of time. I was struggling since yesterday.

What does `?` before `P`?

Comment: @VINAYKr.SHARMA see http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html for details (look for ?P). Simple `P` is an ordinary charackter, while `?P` is a control token. Your original regexp looked for exact match of string `'P<post_type>'` followed by one of the simbols (due to brackets enclosing `[...]`) `a,r,t,i...`

Comment: Oops, I thought it makes parameter optional!